# Intersection of lattice and closed subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, topological-groups, locally-compact-groups, lattices-in-lie-groups

Let $G$ be a locally compact group, $\Gamma$ a (uniform) lattice in $G$. Let $H \leq G$ be a closed subgroup of $G$. Is $H \cap \Gamma$ a (uniform) lattice in $H$?

In the discrete case, this is easy to prove by passing from $\Gamma$, which is a finite-index subgroup, to a finite index *normal* subgroup, and using the isomorphism theorems, but this reduction cannot be done in the continuous case.

What if we assume $G$ and $H$ to be compactly generated? I figure this may help at least in the question about uniform lattices.

Comment: This is false even for subgroups of $G={\mathbb R}$.

Comment: This is also false with $H$ connected, e.g., when $G=\mathbf{R}^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of removing this from the "unanswered" list: the easiest counterexample is probably in $G=\mathbb{Z}$, $H=3\mathbb{Z}$, $\Gamma=2\mathbb{Z}$. As YCor mentioned, you can also have an example where $G$ and $H$ are connected, say if $G=\Bbb{R}^2$, $H$ is a line with irrational slope, and $\Gamma=\mathbb{Z}^2$. Observe that in both examples $\Gamma$ is a uniform lattice, but the intersection is not a lattice at all.